# Python tox in Django

Tags: python, django, tox

I'm using Visual Studio Code. I downloaded a GitLab project to run it and I cloned it from GitLab to Visual Studio Code.
The main issue is running the project in localhost:8000, it is a Django project but there isn't any manage.py file.
It has this tox.ini file:

```
[tox]
envlist = py3

[testenv:run]
usedevelop = true
deps =
commands =
    12apps runserver

[testenv]
usedevelop = true
deps =
    pytest
    pytest-cov
    flake8
    mypy
    django-stubs
    pytest-django
commands =
    pytest --cov=src/twelveapps --cov-report=term --cov-report={env:COV_REPORT_TYPE:html} {posargs}
    flake8 src/twelveapps tests
    mypy src/twelveapps

[coverage:run]
branch = True

[coverage:report]
exclude_lines =
    pragma: no cover
    raise NotImplementedError

[flake8]
per-file-ignores =
    src/twelveapps/**/migrations/*.py:E501

[pytest]
norecursedirs = tests/helpers
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = test_settings
```

I talked to the GitLab project admin and he told me to follow these steps in the terminal:

1. tox -e run --notest
2. mkdir .tox/run/var
3. .tox/run/bin/12apps migrate
4. .tox/run/bin/12apps loaddata tmp/fixtures.json
5. tox -e run

Please, give me the steps I have to follow to run this project in localhost (8000). Thanks.

Obviously, I installed tox and I have a python version which the project supports (3.10).
The first step doesn't work (it gives me the following error: tox run: error: argument -e: expected one argument)

Comment: Maybe `tox run --notest -e run`.